# How can I parent a rig to another rig?

Tags: animation, rigging, parent

I have a rigged object that I'd like one of my characters, who is also rigged, to be holding even as his arms move. How can I attach this object to his hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When animating a character they may need to pick up objects and move them around. The ChildOf constraint is useful for this. The advantage of using the ChildOf constraint is that you can animate the influence to allow the character to pick up and put down the object.

As you can specify an armature and bone to parent to you can also parent different object bones to different character bones, allowing you to have the character hold a piece in each hand and stretch them, or hold the doll body in one hand and lift the doll arm in the other.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I got what you want, you could use a copy location constraint on the "held" armature, to one of the other bones, like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. First position the "held" rig to a bone in the "holding hand". This can be done by selecting a bone in the hand in **edit-mode** and pressing Shift S and choosing "Cursor to selected", then selecting the other rig in **object-mode** and pressing Shift S and choose "Object to cursor".

2.In **pose-mode** right-click on the rig that's to be held and then, holding Shift right-click the other rig. Still holding Shift, Right-click on same bone you postioned the cursor to before. Press Control-P and and choose "Bone" to parent the the second rig to the first.

[image]