# Constrain object to bone (without rigging)

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints

I am trying to connect a gun to a hand bone that is part of a rig.
I tried using Constrain position and Constrain rotation, but it keeps popping off to funny places.

My process was - Align object origin with bone. adding the constraints - with offset (The gun is rigged to the palm bone, and should rotate with offset). Changing Space to local space.

Than when the rig moves the gun flies off[image: Gun in hand - starting position]

Comment: Constraining an object to a bone *is* rigging.

Comment: Use a [child of constraint](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41548/935)

Comment: @RayMairlot - I refer to rigging as the bones and body rig. I want to attach an object that is not part of the body or bones.